# Register File for MIPS Processor

Tags: verilog, flipflop, register, mips

I am writing code for Register file (32 registers, each of 32 bit) for MIPS Single Cycle processor. 
I want writing to happen at the negative edge of the clock. As usual, reading can happen any time (as soon as it gets a proper Register No). Given below is the code for this:

```
module regfile(clk,reset,ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteData, WriteReg, RegWrite, ReadData1, ReadData2);
    input clk, reset;
    input [4:0] ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg;
    input [31:0] WriteData;
    input RegWrite;
    output[31:0] ReadData1, ReadData2;

    //Register File has 32 registers. This module has access to each register through the RegFile array of nets
    wire [32*32-1:0] RegFileAcc;
    wire [0:31] decOut;
    wire [0:31] regClk;
    dec_5to32 dec1(decOut,WriteReg);

    //Creating 32 memory cells, each is a 32 bit register (made up of 32 DFFs)
    genvar j;
    generate for(j=0;j<32;j=j+1)
                begin: regFile
                    assign regClk[j]=(clk & RegWrite & decOut[j]);
                    reg_32bit r1(RegFileAcc[(32*(j+1))-1:32*j],WriteData,regClk[j],reset);
                end
    endgenerate

    //The reading part
    bit32_mux32to1 mux1(ReadData1,RegFileAcc,ReadReg1);
    bit32_mux32to1 mux2(ReadData2,RegFileAcc,ReadReg2);
endmodule
```

Here is the code for the 32 bit register:

```
module reg_32bit(q,d,clk,reset);
    input [31:0] d;
    input clk,reset;
    output [31:0] q;
    genvar j;
    generate for(j=0;j<32;j=j+1)
                begin: reg_loop
                dff d1(q[j],d[j],clk,reset);
                end
    endgenerate
endmodule
```

The code for D F/F is:

```
module dff(q,d,clk,reset);
    input d,clk,reset;
    output q;
    reg q;
    //active low reset
    //we can read the dff using q

    always @(negedge clk)
    begin
        if(reset)
            q<=d;
        else
            q<=1'b0;
    end
endmodule
```

I have implemented a testbench to test the Register File. But I am getting some unexpected output:

Testbench code:

```
module testbench;
    reg [4:0] ReadReg1, ReadReg2, WriteReg;
    reg [31:0] WriteData;
    reg RegWrite,clk,reset;

    wire [31:0] ReadData1, ReadData2;

    regfile rf1(clk,reset,ReadReg1,ReadReg2,WriteData,WriteReg,RegWrite,ReadData1,ReadData2);

    initial
        forever #5 clk=~clk;

    initial 
    begin
        $monitor($time," ReadReg1=%2b ReadReg2=%2b WriteReg=%2b WriteData=%8h ReadData1=%8h ReadData2=%8h \n RegFile=%32h\n",ReadReg1,ReadReg2,WriteReg,WriteData,ReadData1,ReadData2,rf1.RegFileAcc);

                clk=1'b0;
                reset=1'b0;
                RegWrite=1'b0;

        #12     reset=1'b1;
        #6      WriteReg=5'b00000;
                WriteData=32'hAFAFAFAF;
                ReadReg1=5'b00000;
                ReadReg2=5'b00010;
                RegWrite=1'b1;

        #10     WriteReg=5'b00001;
                WriteData=32'hBBBBBBBB;

        #10     WriteReg=5'b00010;
                WriteData=32'hCCCCCCCC;

        #100    $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

**dec_5to32** is the decoder 5*32. **bit32_mux32to1** is mux 32 to 1 (each input is of 32 bits). I have checked them, they work fine. Also, **reg_32bit** and **dff** are also working fine.

[image: The image of Simulation of RegFile]

Comment: **What is your actual question?**  Debugging questions on stack exchange sites must specifically state the difference between the expected output and the output produced.  Also, text is text, please don't use screenshots

Comment: clock gating --VERY bad practise if its for fpga ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer.

1. I strongly suggest you start using a wave-form display for debugging. You can not debug HDL code with $display and $write statements once you get past trivial examples.
2. I noticed that your clock and data have the same delay: clock changes every #5 and your data at #10 and #100. Your clock edges and signal arrive at the same time which is a recipe for disaster.
3. Unless this is a school assignment which forbid this, you should use HDL constructs (I am using different names but you should get the gist)

```
    reg  [31:0] regbank [0:3];
    wire  [1:0] write_index,read1_index,read2_index;
    wire [31:0] write_data;
    ..
       if (WriteReg)
          regbank[write_index] <= write_data;
       read_data1 <= regbank[read1_index];
       read_data2 <= regbank[read2_index];
    ..
```

4. Designing logic on rising and falling edges should be a used only as last resort and only if you really know what you are doing. In normal design it is a big NO NO!

In the example above you can do write forwarding like this:

```
   if (write_index==read1_index)
      read_data1 <= write_data
   else
      read_data1 <= regbank[read1_index];
   if (write_index==read2_index)
   ....
```

Comment: Yes actually its an assignment (Designing single cycle MIPS processor). I changed the delay for data to #8, but still I am having the same problem.

Comment: I can't advise you much more then this without doing to work for you. As a last tip: gating a clock is generally also a bad idea, especially if it has to run on an FPGA. `regClk[j]=(clk & RegWrite...`